# Can you change the current line of execution while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

The debugger lets me drag the little green line pointer, but it seems it has no effect at all and when I step it behaves as though I never dragged it.

Just wondering if the bug is:

- That it's not correctly changing the current execution pointer, or
- That it's allowing me to drag the thing at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xcode changed from being able to drag the instruction pointer from the left, to a completely new visual item and moved it to the far right.

The hamburger icon (shown in the image below) is actually the drag handle for the current instruction pointer.

[image]

Comment: Where has this feature been all my life?!   Works perfect, but Xcode crashes if you move it to a line it doesn't like.

Answer (score 4):

> Can you change the current line of execution while debugging in Xcode?

**YES, it can be changed.**

It works, after you step over, but from next click.

See this example:

Assume the Green arrow is in "a"

```
>>  NSLog(@"a");
    NSLog(@"b");
    NSLog(@"c");
    NSLog(@"d");
    NSLog(@"e");
    NSLog(@"f");
```

It goes to some stack that will be printed when you "Step Over". Then it moves to "b".

as:

```
    NSLog(@"a");
>>  NSLog(@"b");
    NSLog(@"c");
    NSLog(@"d");
    NSLog(@"e");
    NSLog(@"f");
```

Then "b" goes into stack, and it will get printed. Now you change the >> to "e" by dragging, as:

```
    NSLog(@"a");
    NSLog(@"b");
    NSLog(@"c");
    NSLog(@"d");
>>  NSLog(@"e");
    NSLog(@"f");
```

Now "b" will get printed and the pointer will move to next statement i.e. "e".

If you again move it back or forward it will change its place but "e" will be printed, as it is already saved in some stack that is ready to print.

Comment: Interesting, if somewhat bizarre behavior. Good to know it can be changed, but to me it seems kind of pointless if I can't change the *current* (i.e. next) instruction.

Comment: Is it normal, that I can't return back from an "if let" block? I start debugging in the beginning of the function 3 lines after that I enter "if let" block and if I try to return back to the first line of the function I receive error.